# how to elegantly merge two arrays in php, storing values in new keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have at least two arrays (actually four+):

```
$first_names = array(
  '0' => 'Jon'
  '1' => 'David'
  );

$last_names = array(
  '0' => 'Schumacher'
  '1' => 'Johnson'
  );
```

And need to produce:

```
$full_names = array(
  '0' => array('first' => 'Jon', 'last' => 'Schumacher')
  '1' => array('first' => 'David', 'last' => 'Johnson')
);
```

Do not need to preserve original keys (but of course, would prefer to. Need to do this for more than 4 arrays.

Am having trouble finding the 'best' solution (could pop off of each, but that seems likely to produce errors to me).

Comment: should we assume that both arrays **always** have the same length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try array_map:

```
$first_names = array(
    '0' => 'Jon'
    '1' => 'David'
);

$last_names = array(
    '0' => 'Schumacher'
    '1' => 'Johnson'
);

$full_names = array_map(function($first, $last) {
    return compact('first', 'last');
}, $first_names, $last_names);
```

Comment: Does this work for arrays that don't have the same length ?

Comment: sure. array_map will fill shortest one with null values to make both arrays have equal length

Answer (score 0):

Pass in an associative array to the `merge` function in which every key corresponds to what the value of that array will be mapped to in each result item.

```
$allArrays = array(
    "first" => $first_names,
    "last" => $last_names
);
function merge($allArrays){
    $result = array();
    foreach($allArrays as $key=>$array){
         addToResult($result, $key, $array);
    }
    return $result;
}
function addToResult(&$result, $arrayKey, $array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        if(!isset($result[$key])){
            $result[$key] = array();
        }
        $result[$key][$arrayKey] = $value;
    }
}

$full_names = merge($allArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on this:

```
$full_names = array();

foreach( $first_names as $index => $f ) {
    $full_names[] = array('first' => $f, 'last' => $last_names[$index]);
}
```